# Make modal show only when form is submitted successfully

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Boostrap 5 form with validations and when I add the data-bs-target attribute to send button the modal is triggered even if the form has invalid entires.
I want to make the model triggered only when the form is successfully validated.
I tried it with javascript but my code didn't work
Below is my approach:

```
<div class="form-button mt-3">

 <button id="submit" type="submit" class="site-btn " data-bs-toggle="modal"  data-bs-target="">Send</button>

 </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      'use strict'
      const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.requires-validation')
      Array.from(forms)
        .forEach(function(form) {
          form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            if (!form.checkValidity()) {
              event.preventDefault()
              event.stopPropagation()
            }

            form.classList.add('was-validated'),
            document.getElementById('submit').dataset.target ='#confrimationModal';
         

          }, false)
        })
    })()
  </script>
```

Comment: Apart from that issue, you can delegate your submit event handling to `document.addEventListener('submit', function(event) { const tgt = event.target; if (tgt.matches(".requires-validation")) ...`

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the comment just want to ask this line i mean outside the function or should i replace my last line with this ?

Comment: It replaces `const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.requires-validation')
      Array.from(forms)
        .forEach(function(form) {
          form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {` and then just us tgt instead form

Comment: @mplungjan you mean like this 
`<script type="text/javascript">


   
    (function() {
      'use strict'
      const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.requires-validation')
      Array.from(forms)
        .forEach(function(form) {
          form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            const tgt = event.target;
            if (!form.checkValidity()) {
              tgt.matches(".requires-validation")
              event.preventDefault()
              event.stopPropagation()
            }

 
        
 


  </script>`

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry for the trouble but if you can make fiddle I would really appreciate it as I have been trying for hours now

Answer (score 0):

You may programmatically open modal

```
const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('confrimationModal'));
modal.show();
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('submit').dataset.target ='#confrimationModal';
```

ref https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not call anything submit
2. Delegate
3. manually trigger the modal
4. Spelling (confirmationModal)
5. dataset.bsTarget to change `data-bs-target`

```js
(function() {
  'use strict'
  document.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    const tgt = event.target;
    if (tgt.matches(".requires-validation") && !tgt.checkValidity()) {
      event.preventDefault()
      event.stopPropagation()
    } else {
      tgt.classList.add('was-validated');
      document.getElementById('submitButton').dataset.bsTarget = '#confirmationModal';
    }
  })
})()
```

```html
<div class="form-button mt-3">

  <button id="submitButton" type="submit" class="site-btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="">Send</button>

</div>
```